# Setting up Mocha to unit test visualforce page javascript?

Tags: visualforce, unit-test, javascript

I am interested in using a framework like Mocha to test my visualforce page, which is heavily JavaScript.

However, the setup examples I see in the documentation seem to be for more testing your local project files. I am not really sure how I set up Mocha to begin testing the JavaScript in my Visualforce page.

Any setup instructions from anyone who may have managed to get this going would be greatly appeciated!